# Changing the job start date after changing it once already

Tags: professionalism, job-offer

I recently accepted a job offer from a company that is allowing me to start after I graduate from university. During the interview, it was said that the start date was "negotiable to the successful candidate" however, the contract specified August 4th. I had asked if I could start on August 10th instead as I would be graduating on the 7th and then leaving for a wedding and family affair after that. Unfortunately, my family affair has been moved due to my grandpa being scheduled for an eye surgery, and therefore I would have to push my start date back to August 17th. With that being said, it's an important event that relies on my attendance, but I'm really uncomfortable about asking to postpone my start date yet again. Should I commit to what I have already confirmed or should I explain the situation to my new employer and ask if the change is still doable?

Comment: Is the wedding yours or your relative's?

Comment: _that relies on my attendance_ - If you're that critical to the event, and date of the family affair is flexible, can your family adjust the date so it's on a weekend?

Comment: The wedding is my best friend's, and unfortunately the date is set. It works for everyone else in my family because it's during their holidays.

Comment: A  question for you. Suppose the wedding schedule is changed again, are you going to change your start date again? This question is my answer to your question.

Comment: Miss the wedding - if he or she is a good friend they will understand

Comment: I'd ask them to move the start date again. Your grandpas surgery is not your fault and it's your best friends wedding. If they don't understand that this is more important than a start date I wouldn't want to work for them anyway!

Answer (score 6):

1. Your family affair had to be postponed due to your grandpa's eye surgery. If your family felt they had no choice but to postpone their event by one week, then as part of the family, you don't have much of a choice but to postpone, too.
2. You were originally slated to start 10 Aug or about three weeks from today. That's probably far enough in the future that asking for a one-week postponement wouldn't be significantly disruptive to your employer. If your employer has to get their ducks lined up by 10 Aug to onboard you, you are giving them an extra week to line up their ducks.
3. The sooner you ask, the less you inconvenience your employer. Since you posted your question Sunday today, make your request to your employer first thing in the morning on Monday.

Take this episode as an opportunity to showcase yourself as as an excellent, reliable, responsible professional. Apologize for any convenience your request is causing,  explain the obvious: your grandpa's eye surgery that caused the family event to be postponed by one week is an event that is beyond your control. And re-iterate your interest in working with your employer.

This is life, stuff happens.

Answer (score 6):

> Should I commit to what I have already confirmed or should I explain
>   the situation to my new employer and ask if the change is still
>   doable?

You should explain the situation to your new employer, and ask if a change is still doable. If you had already been granted an extension to August 10, an additional 7 days is unlikely to matter much.

Reassure your employer that you still want and are excited about the job, but this is an important unexpected family situation.

If you sense much reluctance on the part of your boss, and it isn't critical that you change your schedule that you might decide to meet your work commitment. That's something you'll have to decide on the fly.

Talk with them as soon as possible, so both they and you can prepare accordingly.

Comment: NO, don't do that.  Even just asking will raise a red flag for them and make the OP seem flaky.

Comment: Given a full explanation of the circumstances, if the employer wants to make a red flag of the situation then this behaviour would be a red flag for me against that employer for not being compassionate or understanding. As Joe said - talk sooner, rather than later!